# Show that $A×A′$ is an affine subspace of $V×V′$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Consider the linear mapping  $ \quad f: V \rightarrow V'$ and $A \subset V$ and $ A' \subset V'$, where A and A' are affine subspaces.

I know if they are affine subspaces, that they can be represented like this:
$$ A=f^{-1}(a')=f^{-1}(f(a)) $$
and similarly $$ A'= f^{-1}(a) $$ where $A'$ is a fiber of $\quad f^{-1}: V' \rightarrow V$   . I'm not too sure about this, because $f$ is not necessarily bijective, so we can't just construct an inverse function, but at the same time, there is a theorem, that says, if $A'$ is an affine subspace of $V'$, said linear mapping exists. Or at least it says at least one such mapping exists.

**Now I want to show, that $A \times A'$ is an affine subspace of $V \times V'$**

Therefore, I construct a linear mapping 
$$g: V \times V' \rightarrow V' \times V, \\(a, f(a)), \mapsto (f(a),f^{-1}(f(a)))$$

because of my representations above
$$ A\times A' = g^{-1} [f(a),f^{-1}(f(a))] $$ 
Therefore, $A\times A'$ is a fiber of $g$ and this proves that it is also an affine subspace.

**Is this correct? This is an exercise from a textbook with no solution provided**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

For starter, let's visualize the linear mapping $f$ using $V = \mathbb R^n$. Consider $U$ the vector subspace parallel to $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ (that goes through $0$).  $U$ has an orthogonal sub-vector-space $U^\perp$.  Now take $f$ to be the orthogonal projection of the entire $\mathbb R^n$ onto $U^\perp$.  Then, since $U$ and $U^\perp$ are orthogonal, $f(U) = \{0\}$, and $U = f^{-1}(0)$ (where $f(U)$ is a shorthand notation for $\{f(u)|u \in U\}$ and $f^{-1}(0)$ a shorthand notation for $\{v\in \mathbb R^n| f(v) = 0\}$; the function need not to be inversible).  Since $A$ is parallel to $U$, there is a $x \in U^{\perp}$ such that $f(A) = \{x\}$ and $f^{-1}(x) = A$.

We used the orthogonality to build $U^\perp$.  But of course any space $B$ isomorphic to $U^\perp$ could provide a valid $f$ function by composing with the isomorphism.  We could even embed $U^\perp$ into a larger vector space and use a $f$ function that is not onto.  But be careful when $f$ is not onto; in that case there are several elements $x$ such that $f^{-1}(x) = \varnothing$.

There is indeed a theorem that proves that build the function $f$ but without using orthogonality.  I quite don't remember the proof with affine spaces, look up in a book.

Now back to your question.  Regardless of your mapping function, if $A$ and $A'$ are affine subspaces of $V$ and $V'$, $A\times A'$ should be an affine subspace of $V\times V'$.  You took $f$ as the mapping function of $A$ and $f^{-1}$ for $A'$.

You started right by taking $g$ such that $g(a,a') = (f(a),f^{-1}(a))$.  Let $w' \in V'$ and $w \in V$ such that $A = f^{-1}(w')$ and $A' = f^{-1}(w)$.  Then obviously,
\begin{equation}
A \times A' = f^{-1}(\{w'\}) \times f(\{w'\}) = g^{-1}(w',w) = \{(a,a')\in A\times A'| g(a,a')=(w',w) \}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect such a thorough response! The geometric interpretation was quite interesting, sometimes I completely forget about it. And your last paragraph was quite a bit more clear than my proof, too! Thank you very much